# ContextMenu Header Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, contextmenu

After spending all day searching for an answer I have to admit defeat and ask for help.

All I need to do is bind the Header item in a context menu to a propety,but all I have tried has failed.

In the code behind I have a simple property that returns a string depending on a flag

Shown Below

```
namespace myNamespace
{

    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {

        // Removed Init code for Clarity ......

        public OptMenuText optMenuText = new OptMenuText();

        public class OptMenuText
        {
            public  bool   menuState { get; set; }
            public  string menuHeader
            {
                get { if (menuState)
                         return "String One";
                      else
                         return "String Two";
                     } 
             }
     }
```

The XAMl code has a ListView bound to a ObservableCollection holding data and various DataTemplates for display
which is working fine. I have read that the Context Menu is not part ot the main application data context and as 
such it requires the DataContext to be specified within the  Tag (Hope I have this right)

Within the ListView is a Context Menu as shown below

```
<ListView Name="listView1" Margin="6"  SelectionMode="Single"                        
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=ConnectCollection}" 
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource templateSelector}" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" >

    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"  >
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding menuHeader}" />
            <Separator />
            <MenuItem Header="Move Item Up"    Click="MenuItemUp_Click" />
            <MenuItem Header="Move Item Down"  Click="MenuItemDown_Click"/>
         </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>

 </ListView>
```

My only issue is that I am unable to bind the MenuItem Header to the string property.

Error Reported is

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'menuHeader' property not found on 'object' ''MainWindow' (Name='This')'.
 BindingExpression:Path=menuHeader; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name='This'); target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Header' (type 'Object')

Can someone PLEASE show me where I am going wrong.

Sarah

Comment: Your ContextMenu XAML is alright. That hints that the DataContext for the ListView is not set. Try to set some property of ListView (BorderThickness for example) through the Binding and see whether it takes effect. If not, then surely the DataContext of the ListView is not correctly set.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see your nested class in the question. The problem is that you have properties in a nested class and that's why binding fails. You will have to expose **optMenuText** as a property rather than a public variable. The code below will work.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window {
     public MainWindow() {
        optMenuText = new OptMenuText();
        InitializeComponent();
     }
     public OptMenuText optMenuText { get; set; }
 }
```

and then use

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding optMenuText.menuHeader}" />
```

for your binding

Comment: Many thanks that has worked but I am sure I understand why. I think I have created an instance of th class 'OptMenuText' which contains the properties I use, but have also created a property for this property so confused. Please could you explain how this works?

Comment: Its just simple class property access. Even if you take your nested class in a separate file, it will work. Your MainWindow has a object optMenuText of type OptMenuText which we are exposing as a public property so that we can bind to it in XAML.

Comment: Many Thanks for your help and explaination, greatly apreciated.